# Is Node decodeURIComponent idempotent? If not, is there an idempotent alternative?

Tags: javascript, node.js, idempotent, decodeuricomponent

Is Node decodeURIComponent idempotent?

Does...

```js
decodeURIComponent(x) === decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(x))
```

for any and all `x`?

If not, is there an alternative that is idempotent? Was trying to think through if this was possible myself.

Comment: It can't be. You can apply it three times on `%252525XX` until you get to `%XX`, and next time you'll get `URI malformed`

Comment: But that you even have this problem is an indication for a much bigger (and potentially security-relevant) problem elsewhere in your code, and _that's_ what you should fix.

Comment: I don't have issues in an application. I actually phrased the question the way I did because I knew it would attract attention haha. (I'm actually interested in trying to put together a different grammar for escaping.)

Comment: Then it's not a practical question and thereby off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I thought you would say that. Which is why is asked a practical version of an adjacent question.

Comment: The question is still the question.

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411999/how-can-i-make-my-very-downvoted-question-more-well-received) as for why it's still probably not a good idea to ask it ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If the string decodes to a new sequence which itself can be interpreted as an encoded URI component, then it can be decoded again to a different string:

```js
const x = '%2521';
console.log(decodeURIComponent(x), decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(x)));
```

`%2521` → `%21` → `!`

Any given string is either *encoded* in a specific format or is *plain text*. You cannot *guess* what it is supposed to be. `%21` could either be the plaintext string "%21", or a URL-encoded string representing "!". You need to *know* which it's supposed to be and interpreted it accordingly. That generally goes for any and all text encoding formats.

Comment: Do you know of a grammar that would be?

Comment: That's not really a practical question, is it?

Comment: Without limiting what values the encoding can represent, there can _never_ be such a solution - it's not possible.

Comment: @CherryDT But, if I did, say by limiting a string to 360 chars, it would be?

Comment: @lmonninger only if the encoded format would be mutually exclusive in its range of possible values with the decoded format - in your example, if any encoded value would be padded to 361 characters minimum (which wouldn't be very useful I think)

Comment: @Imonninger You would need to limit the *kinds* of characters the encoding can represent, not the length. E.g. if you forbade the use of the character "%", then no `%..` sequence could ever decode to another `%..` sequence, and thereby not be recursively decodable. But disallowing the use of specific characters makes this a very impractical encoding format.

Comment: You mean because it's too short or because it adds to length of the string? If the former, I could just chunk it. If the latter, I wouldn't be too worried in JS.

Comment: @CherryDT Know any papers? I only have a passing familiarity with idempotent structures vis CRDTs.

Comment: I believe the correct place to ask this whole question (and I mean the _actual_ question, not the XY problem you intentionally created here) would be https://cs.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: Alright, the folks over here are usually a bit more helpful. But, thanks! Maybe I'll see you over there. You think I should close the actual question? Or, keep it in case someone else is looking?

Answer (score 1):

No

```
> encodeURIComponent('%')
'%25'
> encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('%'))
'%2525'

> decodeURIComponent('%2525')
'%25'
> decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent('%2525'))
'%'

> decodeURIComponent('%2525') === decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent('%2525'))
false
```